# Populating table from table of value

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a largish Oracle table (30M rows) which contains three columns: `ID`, `fieldname`,  `value`. I need a query that will update the target table (which contains 93 columns) from the source data. So if the first row of the source table is `1,'first_name','Robert'` then this will update the row where `ID=1` updating `first_name` column with the value `'Robert'`.

Is this even possible with a query or do I need to process it with another tool?

Comment: You could pivot and merge, but are there rows in the target table which will not have all of their values updated from the source table, and which you want to preserve? Or do all rows in the target table always have references for all 93 columns in the source?

Comment: Some might have address data updated, some might have tombstone data, some might have status indicators updated...some might have all, or some.

Comment: Oh...and some might updated twice (or more) there is a timestamp column used to sort.

Comment: OK, then Gordon's brute-force approach is going to be safer; except the `max` needs to find the latest value rather than the highest if there are duplicates. Otherwise you'd need to have a staging area that got all the target rows with their current values, updated them from the source, and then applied all the changes at once.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  You can do this with a query.  I would suggest building an index on the first table on `id, fieldname, value` and then running the following update 93 times:

```
update targettable tt
    set field1 = (select max(value) from sourcetable st where st.id = tt.id and st.fieldname = 'field1')
    where exists (select 1 from sourcetable st where st.id = tt.id and st.fieldname = 'field1');
```

You can actually write this all as one query, but it gets complicated to handle rows where only some fields are updated.